# Does SG:U end on a cliffhanger?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

I've begun to watch *Stargate: Universe* and am quickly becoming a fan. However, I've recently read that the second (and final) season ends on a cliffhanger (I didn't read what the cliffhanger was) for which there are no plans to wrap up.

Now, ever since the cliffhanger in "Locutus of Borg", *Star Trek:TNG* tortured me for a mere summer, I am wary of continuing to watch SG:U - knowing that I will be left unsatisfied.

Does the series end on a cliffhanger? Is it worth it to watch the entire SG:U series or, does the lack of closure ruin the whole thing?

Comment: They're going to end the series on a cliffhanger? Really? Why would they do that if they've known for basically the entire year that this would be the final season???

Comment: They didn't know while filming that it was going to be the final season.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The finale of the show, which aired last night, was not much of a cliffhanger, and provided excellent closure.  It's an ending that doesn't leave our intrepid heroes in danger, but rather provides a fitting ending.  Here's a full spoiler on the final episode:

> Eli comes up with a plan where they'll put the entire crew in stasis, shut down all the unused systems on Destiny, then set a course that leaves the current galaxy.  This will solve the problem of the drones that have been chasing them throughout this galaxy.  The trip will take 3 years, so everyone gets a visit on Earth to say goodbye to loved ones.  Then everyone goes into stasis, except Eli, as the last stasis pod is damaged.  He has 2 weeks to fix it then get into stasis, or kill himself if he can't fix it.  That's the extent of the cliffhanger.  The episode ends with Eli riding Destiny into the great beyond, happy that he's come into being a member of this crew, intellectually a superior of Rush.

Comment: Don't read the spoiler, but yes, go ahead and invest yourself.  It's a great show cut down before its time by short sighted, misguided, corporate big wigs at Comcast/NBC/Universal/MoronsRUs

Comment: It doesn't answer whether Eli succeeds/survives, or whether the crew survives the long jump, so it leaves one guessing. And perhaps leaves open the possibility of a followup movie.

Comment: Yes, that's a spoiler, but it's the extent of the cliffhanger.  It's pretty clear there's no major threat, and it's likely he'll succeed.

Comment: I thought it was a good way to end the series.  If they want to resurrect it, they just pick up three years later in their time line.

Comment: @Omega, in three years.

Comment: I haven't watched the last episode yet, and I know it won't end the way I want it to. But it is the sort of show you watch for the story and not the ending. It is also the show that convinced me you could rip off an existing show left and right (BSG) and *still* tell a good story. I say go ahead and watch the rest of it, and learn not to rush through the main course thinking only of dessert. :)

Comment: Too bad, the last half of the final season was when things finally started getting better than average...